# PhotoManager.getAssetPathList returning no results in my flutter app on certain phones

Tags: android, flutter, dart

As title suggests, I'm writing a flutter app which calls the following code from the photo_manager package:

`List<AssetPathEntity> assetPaths = PhotoManager.getAssetPathList();`

I've tried this on 4 different android phones.

On 2 phones, `assetPaths` is an empty list, on the other 2 phones `assetPaths` has the full list of media asset paths, as you'd expect.

### Question

Why would this behave differently across various phones?

### What I've Tried/Ruled Out

- All phones definitely have asset folders (directories with images, e.g. 'Camera')
- All phones granted the exact same permission in the exact same way
- There are no filters being applied to this call (I removed any filters to attempt to isolate the cause)
- No errors are being thrown (I'm logging the count out as soon as this call has successfully returned)
- Ruled out any version discrepancies, this is the exact same APK//build
- One of the android devices it works on is my up to date brand new mobile phone. The other it works on is a 4 year old android tablet with an out of date OS, so I'm fairly certain it's not an OS-specific issue (could be wrong)

The package: https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue when I update the photo_manager package from **2.5.2** to **2.6.0**.

I have no idea why it works, since the 2.6.0 changelog doesn't point to anything that might address big issues in 2.5.2. But it works, so for now - solved.